# How to build URI from UriComponentsBuilder from angularjs URL with hash

Tags: java, spring

Hi how do I create an UriComponentsBuilder using "http://test.com/#/signup" successfully? The following code will throw invalid HTTP url.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl("http://test.com/#/signup");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to construct `URI` first and then use it to initialise builder:

```
URI uri = new URI.create("http://test.com/#/signup");
// hash part going to be available like this
String fragment = uri.getFragment();

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri);
```